# Getting all paths from %PATH% variable

Tags: c, windows

I am trying to get all of the paths (%PATH%) added to the environment variables, but I cannot seem to be able to even get all of the paths to then parse them all.

I tried this with "Path", "path", "PATH, "%PATH%":

```
WCHAR Buffer[0x1000];
GetEnvironmentVariableW("%PATH%",
                        Buffer,
                        0x1000);
printf("%ws\n", Buffer);
```

But the last error is always 203 (It cannot find the environment variable)

I also tried the the following but it always returns "=::=::"

```
LPWCH EnvironmentStrings = GetEnvironmentStringsW();
printf("%ws\n", EnvironmentStrings);
FreeEnvironmentStringsW(EnvironmentStrings);
```

How should I go about getting a list of all paths from the %PATH% variable?

Comment: Try `GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"PATH", Buffer,0x1000);`

Comment: Yep. My compiler did not tell me anything about messing up that argument type so I di dnot realize it, thanks!